# Need function like jquery empty() that removes elements added by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a blank div called "content".  Links are later added to "content" using jquery append.  Using [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty) does not work; I am guessing [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty) wont clear the links added by jquery because the links are not added to the DOM?

function should clear, then display new links, but its not clearing the links, just appending to whatever was present.

```
    function getSubRedditLinks(url)
{  
   $("#content").empty(); //doesnt work

   $.getJSON(
      url + suffix, 
      function foo(data) 
      { 
         $("#content").empty(); //doesnt work
         $.each(
            data.data.children, 
            function (i, post) 
            {
               $("#content").append(  '<section>' + 
                                    '<a href="#">' + post.data.title + '</a>' + 
                                    '</section>' );
            } 
         );
      } 
   );
   $("#content").empty(); //doesnt work
}
```

Function is called like this:

```
<li><a class="link" href="#" onclick=getLinks("localhost")>Blogroll</a></li>
```

Apparently, empty() should work.  I simplified my code above, put its not working in the 3 places I put them.  It just keeps adding links to the #content

Comment: it will nice if you put your current code, it will be way more easier to help.

Comment: Agreed - empty() should clear out anything you put in a div. Anything. Text, elements, anything at all. You probably have something else going on..

Comment: what do you expect to happen after you get the json.. see some links or not?

Comment: I get links based on the json, and yes I see them

Comment: still nt understanding what you rproblem is... a jsfiddle would be nice..

Comment: adding before the for loop that appends links, does not work. but adding after it does (which is not what i want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
function getLinks(url)
{
   $.getJSON(
      url + suffix, 
      function(data) 
      { 
         var items = [];
         $.each(
            data.data.children, 
            function (i, post) 
            {
                var section = $('<section></section>').append('<a></a>');
                section.find('a').attr('href', '#post=post-' + i).text(post.data.title);
                items.push(section[0].outerHTML);
            } 
         );
         $('#content').empty().append(items.join(''));
      });
}
```

Comment: earlier it didnt work, but now it works for me. I'm guessing I refreshed the page too fast or something.  Can you explain why this works?

Comment: The emptying of the #content div is being done when the data has been fetched and parsed. GetJSON is an async function. With async functions if ALWAYS better to do the all the work with the data within the success callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(...).remove()` instead... Or `$("#content").html("")`

Comment: I want the content div to stay

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/gzNFK/2/

note: remove the comment to use it

Comment: Have you tried adding $("#content").empty(); before your for loop?